# How can I force a maximum DIV height for multiple inline DIVs coded with display: table-cell?

Tags: html, css

Here is an image of the end result I am trying to achieve, but without success: [image: side-by-side DIVs of varying height with vertically centered text]

I am using display:table-cell + vertical-align:middle for both text-box DIVs so that the text is centered vertically.  But the RIGHT text box renders incorrectly, with the same height as the LEFT text box, even though I am declaring max-height.

Is there a way to enforce a maximum height on the RIGHT text box so that I can still use display:table-cell with vertical-align:middle?  I know that I could always "fudge" the vertical centering with padding and not use display:table-cell, but I'm looking for a cut and dry answer to share with my team as a coding "standard". Vertically centering text within DIVs has become a major hang-up.  Thanks, in advance, for your help.

```
CSS:

#LEFT {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:center;
   border:5px solid #984807;
   background:#FCD5B5;
   width:258px;
   height:315px;
   max-height:315px;
   padding:10px;
   font-size:18px;
}

#RIGHT {
   margin-left:10px;
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:center;
   border:5px solid #984807;
   background:#FCD5B5;
   width:528px;
   height:175px;
   max-height:175px;
   padding:10px;
   font-size:18pt;
}

HTML:

<div id="LEFT">This<br>is<br>the<br>LEFT<br>text<br>box</div>
<div id="RIGHT">This is the RIGHT<br>text box</div>
```

Comment: what browsder are u using? it renders correctly in my screen
http://jsfiddle.net/f7eu7km1/

Comment: Chrome - forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: Use a table with VALIGN. Screw the table-hating purists. Look how much CSS you have there to replace a relatively simple HTML table.

Comment: Why do you use `display:table-cell` if you don't want a tabular layout? Just use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: bottom`.

Comment: @Oriol - Vertically centering DIV text was my original issue, so I'm using the combination of display:table-cell PLUS vertical-align:middle to solve this problem.  But in doing so, it created another issue: forcing cell-height using a tabular DIV layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that you are trying to style two adjacent table cells with different heights. If you can add an additional element inside the second table cell, I think you can accomplish what you are after.

So, with:

```
<div id="LEFT">This<br>is<br>the<br>LEFT<br>text<br>box</div>
<div id="RIGHT"><div>This is the RIGHT<br>text box</div></div>
```

then divide the responsibilities between the outer div #RIGHT and its inner div:

```
#RIGHT {
   padding-left:10px;
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:bottom;
   width:528px;
}
#RIGHT div {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:center;
   border:5px solid #984807;
   background:#FCD5B5;
   width: 578px;
   height:175px;
   max-height:175px;
   padding:10px;
   font-size:18pt;
}
```

See [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/5x3u997c/)

The outer div is the same height as its adjacent table-cell, with padding to make a separation and `vertical-align: bottom` to push the inner div to the bottom. The inner div, since it is no longer adjacent to the div on the left, can then achieve the desired height.

Comment: @bobdye- thank you!  The layout is perfectly what I need. It's unfortunate to have to resort to nested styled DIVs for such a seemingly simple layout, but applying styling to tables is not a coding option for us right now because we have an issue with the TinyMCE editor version we're using in our LMS (but have to live with for a while) which strips CSS code from <td> tags.  Thanks again!